# I got an error message: Property or field 'dal' cannot be found on null when setting up a context variable in watson

Tags: watson-assistant

I'm using Cloud Functions to insert data into a table. I copy-pasted the connection credentials from DB2 Warehouse and set up my context variable with them.

All functions work fine outside watson.

```
"dsn": "DATABASE=BLUDB;HOSTNAME=dashdb-entry-yp-dal09 08.services.dal.bluemix.net;
```

I should be able to connect and insert the data into the table.
Please help.

This is the code I use (provided by the tutorial):

```js
function insertClient(dsn, eventValues) {
  try {
    var conn = ibmdb.openSync(dsn);
    // The timestamp value is derived from date and time values passed in
    var data = conn.querySync("insert into client (name) values('test')", eventValues);
    conn.closeSync();
    return {
      result: data
    };
  } catch (e) {
    return {
      dberror: e
    }
  }
}

function main({
  eventValues,
  __bx_creds: {
    dashDB: {
      dsn
    }
  }
}) {
  return insertClient(dsn, eventValues);
}
```

**Credentials provided by DB2:**

{
  "hostname": "dashdb-entry-yp-dal09-08.services.dal.bluemix.net",
  "password": "",
  "https_url": "https://dashdb-entry-yp-dal09-08.services.dal.bluemix.net:8443",
  "port": 50000,
  "ssldsn": "DATABASE=BLUDB;HOSTNAME=dashdb-entry-yp-dal09-08.services.dal.bluemix.net;PORT=50001;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=dash100113;PWD=;Security=SSL;",
  "host": "dashdb-entry-yp-dal09-08.services.dal.bluemix.net",
  "jdbcurl": "jdbc:db2://dashdb-entry-yp-dal09-08.services.dal.bluemix.net:50000/BLUDB",
  "uri": "db2://dash100113:Qs1_I_5eZUkl@dashdb-entry-yp-dal09-08.services.dal.bluemix.net:50000/BLUDB",
  "db": "BLUDB",
  "dsn": "DATABASE=BLUDB;HOSTNAME=dashdb-entry-yp-dal09-08.services.dal.bluemix.net;PORT=50000;PROTOCOL=TCPIP;UID=dash100113;PWD=;",
  "username": "dash100113",
  "ssljdbcurl": "jdbc:db2://dashdb-entry-yp-dal09-08.services.dal.bluemix.net:50001/BLUDB:sslConnection=true;"
}

Comment: Show the code. Why is it labeled Watson Assistant and neither Db2 nor Cloud Functions?

Comment: For integrating a datatabase like Db2 with Watson Assistant using Cloud Functions, this tutorial has instructions and working code (templates): https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/tutorials?topic=solution-tutorials-slack-chatbot-database-watson#build-a-database-driven-slackbot